# AppendTo or Part in a ParallelDo?

Tags: parallelization

I have a question regarding how memory is managed in parallel. Specifically, I'd like to know what is the better practice when constructing an array within a `ParallelDo`. Both of the following snippets of code demonstrate different ways of constructing the array. First, with `tab[[i]] =`:

```
n = 100;
tab = ConstantArray[0, n];
SetSharedVariable[tab];
ParallelDo[tab[[i]] = n^2, {i, n}];
```

and secondly with `AppendTo`:

```
n = 100;
tab = {};
SetSharedVariable[tab];
ParallelDo[AppendTo[tab, n^2], {i, n}];
```

The question is: Which one is the better practice? Usually for a serial operation I'd expect the first example to be faster (and that's what I would usually do), but in this case the parent kernel may actually send *the entire value* of `tab` to the parallel kernels in order to assign to a part of it. This can cause issues if `tab` is large as it would require potentially a lot of kernel-to-kernel data transfer. I have run some parallel computations that seem to suggest that this might be the case, but I wasn't sure.

So, which way is better?

Comment: I think that `With[{n = 10000}, ary = Array[#^2 &, n]];` would be faster than  both forms that you propose, since it produces a packed array. I think `tbl = ParallelTable[n^2, {n, 10000}];` would be better as well, but not as good as `Array`.

Comment: @m_goldberg In this case I'd like to know which is faster within `ParallelDo`, my real code assigns values to several arrays within the same `ParallelDo` loop

Comment: Then I recommend more realistic examples.

Comment: [This](http://blog.wolfram.com/2011/04/20/mathematica-qa-sow-reap-and-parallel-programming/) explains how to use `Reap`/`Sow` with parallel computations in Mathematica.

Comment: `ParallelDo` is just not suitable for this.  Why don't you collect within subkernels, then merge at the end?  Abusing `SetSharedVariable` for this purpose is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @Szabolcs Why is `ParallelDo` just not suitable for this? And why are shared variables not a good idea, especially if it's at the end of a long calculation?

Comment: @m_goldberg That is not a very constructive comment, this is a minimum working example, specifically to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Guillochon Mathematica's parallel tools are geared towards computations which require no subkernel communication.  What you are asking for is doable without subkernel communication.  Any subkernel communication adds overhead, which is significant in Mathematica.  You were asking, "Which one is the **better** practice? Usually for a serial operation I'd expect the first example to be **faster**". If you are looking for the *best*, as in *fastest* solution, then do not use shared variables. Yes, it is true that in some cases, when the individual computations take very long, it doesn't matter...

Comment: ... much, but in that case the difference between the two approaches you show also won't matter much.  I hope this answers your questions about why shared variables are not a good idea.